# Citations stopped working properly and I cannot think of a reason for it

Tags: citing, biber

After we've had only some minor issues while I was writing my thesis, TeXstudio has today decided to drive me mad. After everything went perfectly well yesterday evening, I only changed some text passages, no modules whatsoever. Of course, no error message is displayed in the logs. And yes, I'm compiling twice: `-pdflatex -makeglossaries -pdflatex -biber -pdflatex`. As I cannot really think of the error, I can only describe you what I'm experiencing, so sorry for the lengthy text.
What's happening now is that it refuses to correctly implement citations now as if it didn't know them. But when I type `\cite{` within the document, it shows all the correct suggestions included in the bib file.
Instead, the .bib entry is written down, e.g.
[image]
Second thing I noticed is that the citations kind of fine for the first chapter but only kind of. When using `this is nonsense \cite{author1}`, it prints *this is nonsense [1]* correctly. If I write `this is \cite{author2} nonsense \cite{author1}`, it changes to *this is [1] nonsense [2]*. But when I remove `\cite{author2}`, and compile again, it is still *this is nonsense [2]* although there is no [1]. And author1 is still listed in the bibliography. But at least it even recognizes the citation and prints it which is more than I can say about the other chapters.

Usually, I'd say that I did involuntarily change some code that leads to this but this issue occurs even when running yesterday's backup which was definitely flawless as it is from 6pm and I compiled the final version around 11pm.
So what I did is I uninstalled both TeXstudio and MiKTeX, removed all related folders and reinstalled it. But still, this issue continues. So is it the code after all?

I don't really know where this error might originate from so here's my total code. I hope it helps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for ä, ö, ü etc
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for equations
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[german, english]{babel} %languages of document
\usepackage{graphicx} %to include images stored on the subfolder images
\usepackage{subcaption} % to create one caption for mulitple images
\usepackage{grffile} % just to be sure that all filenames work
\usepackage{caption} %to configure captions of images and tables
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %for line spacing
\usepackage{booktabs} %used for only tools to create tables
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=IEEE, sorting=none]{biblatex} %for references
\usepackage{pdfpages} %if other pdf documents shall be attached
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1cm, centering,includeheadfoot,left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} %to set frame for text (can be changed)
\usepackage{titlesec} %to have captions start on the right (can be changed)
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} %Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{placeins}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all}     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{wasysym} % für die benutzten Symbole
\usepackage[toc,page,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\rhead{\leftmark}
\chead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper

\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% Abbrevations
% some abbreviations that I can leave out, I think
%
\makeglossaries

% Signature
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[5cm]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm][l]{Datum}      \hfill\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

% Changes URL date from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd for bibliography
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=urldate,
            match=\regexp{([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})},
            replace={$3-$2-$1},
            final]
        }
    }
}
\bibliography{PLATO.bib}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}


\begin{document}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{empty}}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \include{01_title}
    \frontmatter
    \include{Chapter1}
    \include{Chapter2}
    \include{Chapter3}
    \tableofcontents %do not include these 3 in the chapters
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \glsaddall
    \setlength\LTleft{-5pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
    
    % include chapters here
    \mainmatter
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \include{Chapter4}
    \include{Chapter5}
    \include{Chapter6}
    \include{Chapter7}
    \include{Chapter8}    
    \include{Chapter9}

    \include{Appendix}
    
    \backmatter    
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for this odd behavior?

Edit1: As requested the content of the .bgl file:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis PLATO.blg'
[104] biber-MSWIN64:322> INFO - === 
[134] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'Thesis PLATO.bcf'
[291] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
[326] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[327] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'PLATO.bib'
[344] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'PLATO.bib' to PLATO.bib
[369] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'PLATO.bib' for section 0
[377] bibtex.pm:1653> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[676] bibtex.pm:1471> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'PLATO.bib'
[757] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[757] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[757] Biber.pm:4084> INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'en-US'
[757] Biber.pm:4090> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[760] bbl.pm:652> INFO - Writing 'Thesis PLATO.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[761] bbl.pm:755> INFO - Output to Thesis PLATO.bbl
```

Today's .bcf differs from yesterday's by the following lines:

```
<bcf:datalist section="0" 
name="none/global//global/global" 
type="entry" 
sortingtemplatename="none" 
sortingnamekeytemplatename="global" 
labelprefix="" 
uniquenametemplatename="global" 
labelalphanametemplatename="global"> 
</bcf:datalist>
```

Does this explain why it's unable to find more than 2 citekeys?

Edit2: As requested, the log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6ku1io23hn2e5u/Thesis%20PLATO.log?dl=0

Comment: show the content of the .blg file.

Comment: Did you run biber?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there's no .blg file in my folder. I can offer .bbl and .bcf

Comment: Find the blg. (if you have windows, the extension can be hidden and windows perhaps claims that it is a performance file or something like this, but you can open it in your editor).

Comment: @Johannes_B I actually forgot to add this after reinstalling, you are right. I'll edit it in my post. The queue is not -pdflatex -makeglossaries -pdflatex -biber -pdflatex but the issue is still there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, it was not listed as .bgl type but search function showed it. The content is too long for a single comment, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Additional the additional info is now part of the original posting as requested by @Johannes_B.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer did you find anything suspicious in the log file?

Comment: the log mentions an open group at the end: ### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 136 (\begingroup). That means that you somewhere have an { or similar that is not correctly closed. But I can't say if this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detail! Line 136 is `\tableofcontents` in my file. Does this mean something is off with a headline or could it be anything? I mean in Chapter 1 which is **before** the ToC, citations work kind of fine, after the ToC it's flawed.

Comment: Aaah, we're getting close to the source! In my Appendix, I have `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
 \begingroup
 \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
 \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
\makeatother` (some code that I have from the internet that makes it look nicer in the ToC. However, I think this is the `\begingroup` which is messing up and it interferes with the Bibliography which comes afterwards! If I comment out this code, the citations work again! Now I just have to find out how to close this properly.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so, so much for your help! I would have never found this! Consider yourself closely hugged! :D

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up an answer here? Or do we close as 'some code not shown in the question caused the error'?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by some code not shown in the question.